# Как в laravel добавить запись в таблицу, если она имеет лишь поле id и timestamps?

Tags: php, laravel

Я через ORM реализую заполнение таблицы. И не пойму как сделать, чтобы у меня просто создавалась новая запись, не вводя в неё данные - т.к. id автоинкремент, timestamps сам ставит. Тоесть таблица из 3 полей - id created_at updated_at. Таблица представляет собой записи-транзакции.

первая транзакция сделана тогда-то.
вторая транзакция сделана тогда-то.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял вопрос. Нужно вставить запись, если имеется 3 поля. Где id - primary key, created_at и updated_at - заполняются default now()?

```
DB::table('users')->insert();
```